# DuplicateKeyException in the integration test

Tags: testing, grails

I have two `spock` tests in a class. Both tests have the same setup:

```
Class MySpec {

  def "Test1"() {
    setup:
      def book = new Book(title: 'Something')
      book.id = 1
      book.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    // rest of the test
  }

  def "Test2"() {
    setup:
      def book = new Book(title: 'Something')
      book.id = 1
      book.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    // rest of the test
  }

}
```

NOTE: The `Book` domain has an `assigned` `id` so I have to explicitly set it when saving.

The first test works but the next one fails with `org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException`. I thought that the database gets rolled back between the tests (and I shouldn't get this error). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Also show Book domain. This should not be a problem. Specs are cleaned up after execution. It works as expected in 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

Add `static transactional = false` ti this class. **The reason for that is that as well as Services being executed in a transaction so too are integration tests. So because there is already a transaction in play, there is no transaction bound to the method of the service (that your probably call in the test). Thus, the rollback never happens.**
Any test we make non-transactional we need to add appropriate `tearDown` code.

Another solution:

Just make this class as a **Unit** test. Rollback will work properly.